# Axis getting swapped while plotting

Tags: plotting

I am havings data set with 6 coloums and I am trying to plot two coloumns out of 6, but my axis are getting swapped.

This is what I am trying

```
Clear [Data]
$TextStyle = {FontWeight -> "Bold", Font -> "Arial", FontSize \[RightArrow] 12};
Data = Transpose[Import["21.csv"]];
Ampvsf0 = Transpose[Union [{Data[[1]]}, {Data[[2]]}]]
graph = ListPlot[Ampvsf0]
```

Here is the data file [21.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1le0AETtfY7qJd9UEiFb9fdIv6YqApy2C/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[Data]

$TextStyle = {FontWeight -> "Bold", Font -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12};
```

Import the data without transposing it.

```
Data = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/21.csv"];
```

Extract the first two columns

```
Ampvsf0 = Data[[All, 1 ;; 2]] // Union;

graph = ListPlot[Ampvsf0]
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to plot column 1 and column 4 but it was trying to make a union of all of them.

Comment: `Data[[All, {1, 4}]]` Read the documentation for `Part`

Comment: You need to edit the question to clarify what you are trying to do. You provided code that doesn't do what you want and left us to guess what you were trying to do. Read the documentation for `Union` it doesn't do what you apparently think it does.